# Parse First Line from CSV and Split it Into 2 DIVs

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv, google-sheets

I'm trying to load the first two entries of a google spreadhseets CSV into two seperate divs.

I need to do this so that the featured video in my dynamically updating gallery has the first line of the CSV already appearing in it when the page is loaded, before my javascript click function loads one of the other videos from my PHP array.

Here's my HTML/PHP:

```
<div class="gallery">
            <div class="feature"><div>First entry on CSV line 1</div><div>Second entry on CSV line 1</div></div>
            <div class="thumbs">
            <?php
                    $f = fopen("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/+MyKey+/pub?output=csv", "r");

                    while (!feof($f)) { 

                       $arrM = explode(",",fgets($f)); 

                       echo "<a href=\"#\" title=\"{$arrM[0]}\" rel=\"{$arrM[1]}\" class=\"galImg\"><div class=\"comThumbDiv\"><img src=\"{$arrM[2]}\" class=\"thumb\" border=\"0\"/></div></a><br>"; 

                    }

                    fclose($f);
             ?>
             </div>
        </div>
```

And here's my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".galImg").click(function() {
            var image = $(this).attr("rel");
            var title = $(this).attr("title");
            $('.feature').html('<div style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);"><iframe width="890" height="500" src="' + image + '"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div class="vidTitle"><br>' + title + '</div>');
        });
    });
```

Any ideas how I might do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is correct and working fine. Are you searching better solution?
Could you more specify the problem?

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Hey, so right, the code above is working, I'm just asking if there's a way to load the first two entries of the CSV, in other words what in PHP references would be $arrM[1] and $arrM[0] in the "feature" div before the js click function happens, in other words when the page is loaded already having those two parsed lines appear in seperate divs within the "feature" div.

Comment: `echo '<div class="feature">
  <div style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);"><iframe width="890" height="500" src="' . $arrM[1]  . '"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class="vidTitle"><br>' . $arrM[0] . '</div>  
</div>';`

Comment: Okay, so I can put this code in another php block before the "thumbs" div, but it still produces an array of all of the lines from the CSV. Do you know if there's any way to stop the array after the first row of the CSV? I only want the first row of the CSV to appear in the "feature" div.

Comment: @BowT Yes, of course. If you want break after get first line you could put after echo `exit` or modify while loop: while (!feof($f) && $counter <1) { $counter++, and set $counter value to 0 before while.

Comment: Cool, the second option works great for my purposes. I'm new to PHP, so doing a lot of code sampling and understand very little about the syntax thus far. Thanks for the help!